# Cannot push files to SD card in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, ddms

I am trying to send images and songs to the Android Emulator, but the SD card is on read- only mode. How can I change the permission of the folder (I am using Winds as my OS).

These are the error:

**Error 1**

**ddms transfer error: Read_only file system 
Failed to push selection: Read-only file system**

**Error 2**
when trying to create a folder inside the SD card, this error appears

**mkdir failed to /sdcard/New Folder, Read-only file system**

Answer (score 2):

> Just go to you avd manager and select the edit option on right
>   corner, and then click on show advance settings , in sd card option ,
>   select studio managed and give some memory (like 500mb) and then finish.
>       close the emulator and reopen the same emulator again.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. the problem was I did not have enough memory. I had 200 MB and changed to 500 MB and it worked

Comment: I want to add `/system/etc/hosts` file on AVD by Android Studio

Comment: It's strange, I had 100 MB, I increase it to 250 MB and it works. Perhaps the message is misleading, it should be "insufficient" instead of "can't write".